# How can i get subsidiaryList of locations from NetSuite?

Tags: php, search, netsuite

I prepared LocationSearch object and sent to NetSuite server
But in result, subsidiaryList of Location Object always is null, it should be same with parent property.

```
 [record] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Location Object
                        (
                           [name] => zzzzzz
                           [parent] => RecordRef Object
                                (
                                    [internalId] => 7
                                    [externalId] => 
                                    [type] => 
                                    [name] => xxxxxxxx
                                )
                            [includeChildren] => 
                            [subsidiaryList] => 
                            [isInactive] => 
                            [tranPrefix] => 
                            [attention] => 
                            [addressee] => zzzz
                            [addrPhone] => 
                            [addr1] => 
                            [addr2] => 
                            [addr3] => 
                            [city] => 
                            [state] => 
                            [zip] => 
                            [country] => _zz
                            [addrText] => zzzzz
                            [override] => 
                            [logo] => 
                            [makeInventoryAvailable] => 1
                            [makeInventoryAvailableStore] => 1
                            [classTranslationList] => 
                            [customFieldList] => 
                            [internalId] => 11
                            [externalId] => 
                            [nullFieldList] => 
                        )
                ................
```

$paramtypesmap of class Location

```
"name" => "string",
"parent" => "RecordRef",
"includeChildren" => "boolean",
"subsidiaryList" => "RecordRefList",
"isInactive" => "boolean",
"tranPrefix" => "string",
"attention" => "string",
"addressee" => "string",
"addrPhone" => "string",
"addr1" => "string",
"addr2" => "string",
"addr3" => "string",
"city" => "string",
"state" => "string",
"zip" => "string",
"country" => "Country",
"addrText" => "string",
"override" => "boolean",
"logo" => "RecordRef",
"makeInventoryAvailable" => "boolean",
"makeInventoryAvailableStore" => "boolean",
"classTranslationList" => "ClassTranslationList",
"customFieldList" => "CustomFieldList",
"internalId" => "string",
"externalId" => "string",
```

How can i get subsidiaryList of locations from NetSuite ?
Thank you very much
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have "body fields only" set as a preference?? If so, turn it off.

Comment: I turn it off, and i can get subsidiaryList.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave Weiss.

Comment: Where can I find this setting?

Comment: @SudipBolakhe - on each request, there is a preferences object you can modify. It's in that object.